# Is uniform differentiablity symmetric?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$,
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(y)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$
when $|x-y| < \delta$.

*Note: Initially, I had incorrectly written the following, as Theo Bendit and Anne Bauval helped correct:*

<s>For all $\varepsilon > 0$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(y)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$
when $|x-y| < \delta$.</s>

*End note.*

Does this imply that $$\left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(x)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$?

Intuitively, it seems it must: The first equation is stating that the slope of the secant is arbitrarily close to the derivative at one point of the secant.  This should apply to *both* points of the secant -  there's no way to distinguish one point $(y)$ from the other $(x)$.

Yet, algebraically, I haven't been able to prove it.  Is my assertion true? Can it be proven algebraically? Is it true if we replace $f'$ with arbitrary function $g$? Or does the proof somehow depend on the nature of derivative? What am I missing?

Comment: You should be a little careful with your quantifiers here. I've interpreted what you've written as garden-variety differentiability, where the $\delta$ is permitted to vary with $x$ (by virtue of the fact that it's mentioned after the $x$). I'm guessing that it should be: "For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that whenever $|x - y| < \delta$,$$\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} - f'(y)\right| \le \varepsilon."$$Would that be what you're intending?

Comment: @TheoBendit No, actually, I was referring to the "uniform differentiability" developed in Rudin PMA.  It's intentionally not the standard usage: in this usage, $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$ but _not_ $x$.

Comment: Does "in  *this* usage" denote the "standard" one, or Rudin's and yours?

Comment: @AnneBauval Rephrasing for clarity: In the usage of the OP, which follow's Rudin's concept of _uniform differentiability_, $\delta$ may depend on $\varepsilon$ but not on $x$ (unlike the more common usage which allows $\delta$ to depend on $x$ as well).

Comment: Then why did you answer "no" to Theo instead of correcting your post? We would have answered you sooner.

Comment: As far as I understand, my post is correct.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding Theo's question.

Comment: Look at your first line: it makes $\delta$ depend on $x.$ And read Theo's first comment more carefully.

Comment: Aha! Thank you - the error was indeed mine, and I completely misunderstood @TheoBendit's question.  Thank you both.  I've corrected the question (keeping the original intact as well for reference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be explicit about the logical form of the definition, it is:

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(y)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$
if $|x-y| < \delta$.

By uniformly swapping the variables $x$ and $y$, this is obviously equivalent to:

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} - f'(x)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$
if $|x-y| < \delta$.

But
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} - f'(x)\right \rvert = \left \lvert \frac{-(f(x)-f(y))}{-(x-y)} - f'(x)\right\rvert = \left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(x)\right \rvert.$$

So, the original definition is equivalent to:

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$
$$\left \lvert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} - f'(x)\right \rvert \leq \varepsilon$$
if $|x-y| < \delta$.

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct then, to generalize: For all $c \neq d$, we have $$\frac{a-b}{c-d}  = \frac{b-a}{d-c}.$$

Comment: Your post makes this so clear that I'm confused as to why I found this so elusive.  Assuming you were teaching a class, do you have any sense of students' difficulties you'd anticipate?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Maybe the reason you were confused is that you were assuming the proof would be more algebraically tricky than it is. The main point here is just a logical one: that we get equivalent statements after uniformly substituting variables. That is the sort of thing worth pointing out to students, I suppose, since many math students won't have studied formal logic. The basic point is easily illustrated with examples like: "'Every x is less than some y' is equivalent to 'every y is less than some x.'"

Answer (score 2):

Now your assertion is true, even if you replace $f'$ by any function $g,$ and $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ by any other *symmetric* function $F(x,y).$ Even more generally, if
$$\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\quad(|x-y|<\delta\implies h(F(x,y),y)\leq \varepsilon)$$
then (by change of notations)
$$\forall(y,x)\in\Bbb R^2\quad(|y-x|<\delta\implies h(F(y,x),x)\leq \varepsilon),$$
which is equivalent to
$$\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\quad(|x-y|<\delta\implies h(F(x,y),x) \leq \varepsilon)$$
by symmetry of $F,$ of the distance, and of $\forall x\forall y.$